# How to pass the primary key from a Blazor Grid to a dialog box so I can edit the record (using SyncFusion Controls)

Tags: blazor-server-side, syncfusion, asp.net-blazor, syncfusion-blazor

My Blazor app has a grid with a custom toolbar with "Create" and "Edit" actions, like so...

[image]

I have hooked up the "Create New" action so that I can call a reusable dialog box to create a record.

However, I cannot figure out how to pass the unique key of the edited record so that I can use the same reusable dialog box to edit a record.

In the My_Templates.razor file, I check to see if we have hit the Add or the Edit button and take the appropriate action. But in the edit action I do not know how to pass the unique key of the selected record. That is the first problem.

Here is the code for My_Template.razor page:

```
@page "/"
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Inputs
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Navigations
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Popups

<ReusableDialog @ref="dialog"></ReusableDialog>
<SfGrid @ref="Grid" AllowPaging="true" DataSource="@Orders" Mode="EditMode.Dialog" AllowSorting="true" Toolbar="ToolbarItems">

    <GridEvents OnToolbarClick="OnClicked" TValue="Order"></GridEvents>
    <GridEditSettings AllowAdding="true" AllowEditing="true" AllowDeleting="true" Mode="EditMode.Dialog" Dialog="DialogParams"></GridEditSettings>
    <GridColumns>
        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(Order.templateID) HeaderText="Template ID" IsPrimaryKey="true" TextAlign="TextAlign.Right" Width="20"></GridColumn>
        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(Order.owner) HeaderText="Owner" ValidationRules="@(new ValidationRules { Required = true })" Width="120"></GridColumn>
        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(Order.users) HeaderText="Users" TextAlign="TextAlign.Left" Width="130"></GridColumn>
        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(Order.description) HeaderText="Description" TextAlign="TextAlign.Left" Width="130"></GridColumn>
        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(Order.fundType) HeaderText="Fund Type" TextAlign="TextAlign.Left" Width="120"></GridColumn>
    </GridColumns>
</SfGrid>

@code{

    public Index IndexPage = new Index();

    SfDialog infoDialog;
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; } = false;
    private List<Object> ToolbarItems = new List<Object>()
{
        new ItemModel() { Text = "Create New Template", TooltipText = "Add", PrefixIcon = "e-icons e-update", Id = "Add", },
        new ItemModel() { Text = "Edit Template", TooltipText = "Edit", PrefixIcon = "e-icons e-update", Id = "Edit"}
        };

    ReusableDialog dialog;

    public void ReturnValue(string value)
    {
        if (value == "Ok Clicked")
        {
            // your code execution
        }
        else
        {
            // your code execution
        }
    }

    public async Task OnClicked(Syncfusion.Blazor.Navigations.ClickEventArgs Args)
    {

        if (Args.Item.Id == "Add")

            //Call Dialog Box Here
            dialog.Title = "This is the Add Title";
            dialog.Text = "This is the add text";
            dialog.OpenDialog();

        if (Args.Item.Id == "Edit")

            //Call Dialog Box Here
            dialog.Title = "This is the Edited Title";
            dialog.Text = "This is the edited text";
            dialog.templateID = 2; //WHAT DO I PUT HERE
            dialog.OpenDialog();

    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Orders = Enumerable.Range(1, 75).Select(x => new Order()
        {
            templateID = 1000 + x,
            owner = (new string[] { "Bryan", "Amy", "Bob", "Jerry", "Zoe" })[new Random().Next(5)],
            users = (new string[] { "Bryan", "Amy", "Bob", "Jerry", "Zoe" })[new Random().Next(5)],
            description = (new string[] { "Template 1", "Template 2", "Template 3", "Template 4", "Template 5" })[new Random().Next(5)],
            fundType = (new string[] { "Wire", "ACH", "Reserve Funds for Wire", "Wire", "Wire" })[new Random().Next(5)],
        }).ToList();
    }

    public List<Order>
    Orders
    { get; set; }

    private DialogSettings DialogParams = new DialogSettings { MinHeight = "800px", Width = "1200px" };

    SfGrid<Order>
        Grid
    { get; set; }

    public void Clicked()
    {
        Grid.StartEditAsync();
    }

    public IEditorSettings OrderEditParams = new NumericEditCellParams
    {
        Params = new NumericTextBoxModel<object>
        ()
        { Placeholder = "Order ID" }
    };

    public class Order
    {
        public int? templateID { get; set; }
        public string owner { get; set; }
        public string users { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string fundType { get; set; }

    }
}
```

The second problem is that in my ReusableDialog box I am not sure how to retrieve the record. Or perhaps I should pass the entire record from the view above?

Here is my code for the reusableDialog.Razor file:

```
@page "/reusable-dialog"
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Popups
@using Blazor_EditForm.Data

<div id="DialogTarget">
    <SfDialog Target="#DialogTarget" Width="1200px" IsModal="true" ShowCloseIcon="true" @bind-Visible="@IsOpen">
        <DialogTemplates>
            <Header><h4 class="modal-title">@templateID</h4></Header>
            <Content>
                <EditForm Model="@employee" OnValidSubmit="@OnValidSubmit">
                    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
                    <label>Owner</label>
                    <InputText id="owner" @bind-Value="employee.owner" class="form-control" />
                    <label>Users</label>
                    <InputText id="users" @bind-Value="employee.users" class="form-control" />
                    <label>Description</label>
                    <InputTextArea @bind-Value="employee.description" class="form-control" rows="4" />
                    <label>Fund Type</label>
                    <p></p>
                    <InputRadioGroup @bind-Value="employee.fundType" class="form-control">
                        @foreach (var option in rdOptions)
                        {
                            <InputRadio Value="option" /> @option <br />
                        }
                    </InputRadioGroup>
                </EditForm>
            </Content>
        </DialogTemplates>
        <DialogButtons>
            <DialogButton Content="OK" IsPrimary="true" OnClick="@OkClick" />
            <DialogButton Content="Cancel" IsPrimary="false" OnClick="@CancelClick" />
        </DialogButtons>
    </SfDialog>
</div>

@code {

    //Parameters
    [Parameter]
    public int templateID { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public Employee employee { get; set; } = new Employee();
    //public Employee employee { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string ButtonText { get; set; } = "Save";
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback OnValidSubmit { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public bool IsOpen { get; set; } = false;
    [Parameter]
    public string IsClosed { get; set; }

    List<string> rdOptions = new List<string> { " Fund Type 1", " Fund Type 2", " Fund Type 3" };

    SfDialog DialogObj;

    public Index IndexPage = new Index();
    //public MyTemplates  My_Templates = new My_Templates();


    public void OpenDialog()
    {
        IsOpen = true;
        this.StateHasChanged();
    }

    private void OkClick()
    {
        IsOpen = false;
        this.StateHasChanged();
        this.IsClosed = "Ok Clicked";
        //IndexPage.ReturnValue(this.IsClosed);
    }

    private void CancelClick()
    {
        IsOpen = false;
        this.StateHasChanged();
        this.IsClosed = "Cancel Clicked";
        //IndexPage.ReturnValue(this.IsClosed);
    }
}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Very new to Blazor, so if this is the wrong approach, would be very happy to know of a design pattern for adding/editing/deleting records from a grid using a dialog box.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We suggest you to pass the entire selected record details to Reusable Dialog component using **GetSelectedRecordsAsync**() method of Grid. Record has to selected in Grid to perform an edit operation. So selected records details can retrieved using **GetSelectedRecordsAsync** method of Grid.

We have fetched the selected records details and displayed in reusable dialog. Refer the below code example.

```
public async Task OnClicked(Syncfusion.Blazor.Navigations.ClickEventArgs Args)
{
    if (Args.Item.Id == "Add")
    {
        //to prevent the default action
        Args.Cancel = true;
        //Call Dialog Box Here
        dialog.Title = "This is the Add Title";
        dialog.Text = "This is the add text";
        dialog.employee = new Order();
        dialog.OpenDialog();
    }
    if (Args.Item.Id == "Edit")
    {
        //to prevent the default action
        Args.Cancel = true;
 
        var selected = await Grid.GetSelectedRecordsAsync();
        if (selected.Count > 0)
        {
            //Call Dialog Box Here
            dialog.Title = "This is the Edited Title";
            dialog.Text = "This is the edited text";
            dialog.employee = selected[0]; //WHAT DO I PUT HERE
            dialog.OpenDialog();
        }
        else
        {
            //show custom dialog to select a record.
 
        }
    }
```

Kindly refer the below modified sample for your reference

Sample: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/DataGrid_Server-2003338358.zip